# Where is Trust Centre for Outlook 2003

Tags: c#, security, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I've got an Outlook addin which is disabled indicating that it is not in the Trusted source list. I found the Trust Centre for outlook 2010 but couldn't find where it is located for outlook 2003.

could someone please show me whether I should look at?

Answer (score 2):

In 2003 the location is a little different.
Open Outlook, click Tools, then Options, then click on Security Tab and then under the Download Pictures section.

Comment: "under the Download Pictures section" ? I've got "Change Automatic Download Settings.." only there. There is no Trust centre?

Comment: Actually I have been looking for "Apply macro security settings to installed add-ins" which generally comes under Trust Centre.